# How do I open different types of web browsers through Python?

Tags: python, linux, firefox, raspberry-pi, chromium

I'm trying to run a script on my Raspberry-Pi through Python that opens a specific search on Chromium, then switches over to Firefox and does another search. I've already gotten the Chromium part done, the problem here is that "webbrowser.open()" can only open the default browser.

Can I set it to open a specific browser?

Is there a way to open URLs on Firefox specifically through Python?

Is there a script to set a default browser?

A possible solution could be finding a Python script to change the default web browser to Firefox after it opens Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

```
webbrowser.get("firefox").open(myurl)
#
webbrowser.get("opera").open(myurl)
```

You can find the list here: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.register

Comment: So would I put this down instead of "webbrowser.open()"?

Comment: With argument to `get`, you're setting the browser that will open *myurl*.